# FAQ toggle in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am building a faq page and can't think of a function for this. Basically I have a `.json` file with questions and answers and I want `onClick` to `toggle` the answer that is meant to be hidden and `onMouseOut` to hide the answer again. 
Apreciate your help

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import questionData from '../components/data/faquestions.json';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import '../assets/toggleQue.scss';


const Faq = ({ data }) => {
    
    
    return(
      <div className="grid-faq-container">
        <div className="question">
          <p><strong> {data.question}</strong> </p>
        </div>
        <div className="answer">   
          <p>{data.answer}</p> 
        </div>
      </div>
    )
}

const Faqs = () => {
  return (
    <>
    <h1>FAQs</h1>
    <div className="faqIteration">
      {questionData && questionData.map((e, key) => {
        return (
          <Faq
            data={e}
            key={key} 
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
    </>
  );
};

Faq.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.object,
};

export default Faqs;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood you right.

OnClick you add an identifier for the Question into an array. OnMouseOut you can then check, if the question where your mouse just left is inside this array. If yes, hide it. If no, do nothing. You have to add the onMouseOut listener to every question.